# Remove Single IDs from local administrator group

Tags: powershell

I want to delete individual ID's from Administrator group

I have below code to get the members and delete them

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators'
```

```
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
$User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
$AdminGroup.Remove($User.Path)
Write-Host "Successfull:" $ComputerName
```

the problem I am facing is **how to identify the single/individual IDs in the group**.

below is one sample output from one of the server I fetched the members where there is no individual IDs present

```
Name                                                 SID                                               PrincipalSource ObjectClass
----                                                 ---                                               --------------- -----------
AUTO1AP\csgadm#                                      S-1-5-21-126948685-454775200-1760099607-500                 Local User       
ZA\                                                  S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932         ActiveDirectory Other      
ZA\A-Auto$                                           S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932-1423106 ActiveDirectory User       
ZA\A-Server Administrators                           S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932-128673  ActiveDirectory Group      
ZA\A92361                                            S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932-1423726 ActiveDirectory User       
ZA\A-SAN-AUTO                                        S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932-1475616 ActiveDirectory User       
ZA\Domain Admins                                     S-1-5-21-3095416536-3097367016-2845470932-512     ActiveDirectory Group
```

I have the above data now and I want to delete the Individual account from this which is **ZA\A92361** ( here I know this is the individual account but in actual case I need to find out and delete)

Please let me know on this

Comment: The default table output of `Get-LocalGroupMember` does not show there is in fact also a property `.SID`. Is that the `ID` you are looking for? (`Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' | Format-Table *`)

Comment: @Theo: I need to identify the members (Individual IDs) in the admin group and remove them. In the example output there is no single ID. e.g. if mine and your IDs are part of admin group then I have to identify and delete them.

Comment: But then, what _id_ do you mean? Get-LocalGroupMember already returns their domain\user login name and also their SID. That should be enough to identify the ones you need to delete I would think?

Comment: @Theo: Yes. IDs means the account. using the domain\user login name and also their SID it is not possible to identify because the IDs and other accounts all starts with same initials. I was looking for some property to identify

Comment: @Theo: I have updated the question with more clarification. hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is still not clear to me what you mean by *identify* the users you want to remove, I believe the `Get-LocalGroupMember` cmdlet returns everything you need to identify them.

```
$ADusersToRemove = 'jdoe', 'cblossom'  # example some SamAccountNames of users to remove from the group
# from these users to remove, get an array of their Security IDs
$ADsidsToRemove = $ADusersToRemove | ForEach-Object { (Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).SID }

# get a list of members of the local group, AD users only
$allADMembers = Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' -and $_.PrincipalSource -eq 'ActiveDirectory' }

# remove the wanted AD users from the group
$ADmembersToRemove = @($allADMembers | Where-Object { $ADsidsToRemove -contains $_.SID })
if ($ADmembersToRemove.Count) {
    Remove-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' -Member $membersToRemove.SID
}
```

If you also want to remove LOCAL users (not AD), you can do something similar

```
# get an array of LocalPrincipal objects
$LocalUsersToRemove = @(Get-LocalUser -Name 'someguy', 'anotheruser' )
if ($LocalUsersToRemove.Count) {
    Remove-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' -Member $LocalUsersToRemove
}
```

---

If as you say you want to exclude service accounts, then this question really is how to distinguish between a service account and a normal user account.

I have no idea how you have organized your AD, but therfe are several options of course:

1. you can have all service accounts start their samaccountname with a special prefix, like `svc_` or something.
   Then you can alter the filter to become

```
Where-Object { $ADsidsToRemove -contains $_.SID -and (($_.Name -split '\\') -notlike 'svc_*')}
```

2. you can have a special OU where all service accounts are stored like `OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=Company,DC=com`
   Then you can use filter

```
Where-Object { $ADsidsToRemove -contains $_.SID -and ((Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID).DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=Company,DC=com')}
```

3. you can have the Description property of the service accounts all contain the words `Service account`
   Then you can use filter

```
Where-Object { $ADsidsToRemove -contains $_.SID -and ((Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID -Properties Description).Description -notlike '*Service account*')}
```

4. maybe you have used an Extension attribute on service accounts to test like `ExtensionAttribute1=svc`
   Then you can use filter

```
Where-Object { $ADsidsToRemove -contains $_.SID -and ((Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID -Properties ExtensionAttribute1).ExtensionAttribute1 -notlike 'svc')}
```

The possibilities are almost endless as you can see..

Comment: Thanks for your response. but as you mentioned in your solution `$ADusersToRemove = 'jdoe', 'cblossom' `, in my case I don't have this data. I have to identify the user accounts first

Comment: Identify means I have to fetch the members which are user account (like we can have groups, service account in a group). `Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' -and $_.PrincipalSource -eq 'ActiveDirectory' }
` this will fetch the service accounts as well.

Comment: @EmptyCoder Sure, but I can't tell how your service accounts distinct from normal users in your environment.. Are they all inside a special OU or are all of them named `svc_something` for instance?

Comment: Yes. It's starts with same. that's the problem. that was the reason I was looking if there is some AD property through which we can identify.

Comment: @EmptyCoder Please see my edit